# Using JSON objects instead of arrays in Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

In [Datatables](http://datatables.net/), is there a way to use data that is sent from the server as an array of JSON objects? The format that seems to be expected is an array of arrays.

http://jsbin.com/oqisiz/1

This format works:

```
var table1Data = [['John', 36], ['Jane', 25]];
```

But this does not:

```
var table2Data = [{Name: 'John', Age: 36}, {Name: 'Jane', Age: 25}];
```

(Please just answer factually whether Datatables supports this or not, instead of turning this into a debate of which format is better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [documented here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html) - just use `mData` to specify which columns you need instead of `sTitle`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "sources/objects.txt",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "engine" },
            { "mData": "browser" },
            { "mData": "platform" },
            { "mData": "version" },
            { "mData": "grade" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```